# elastic search nest version 5.x: how to extract elastic query from nest query?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We are hitting MultiSearch query from our nest client. The query looks like:

```
IMultiSearchResponse result = client.MultiSearch(...);
```

The result returned has following properties, AllResponses, ApiCall, DebugInformation, IsValid, OriginalException, ServerError, TotalResponses, Non-Public members.

Where can I find the elastic search request queries in DSL format that were fired in this object? I want to check it in sense client

Comment: Did you check official documentation? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-fiddler.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `client`'s serializer to serialize your request into raw query.

```
IMultiSearchRequest request = new MultiSearchDescriptor()...
var rawQuery = client.Serializer.SerializeToString(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of type IMultiSearchResponse will have a property "DebugInformation". Just check the "JSON visualizer" for that and you will get all the information.